# How do I set plan_cache_mode to force_custom_plan in my application?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp, timescaledb

I have a Spring Boot application with a REST service. I'm using PorstgreSQL as my database with TimescaleDB. I'm trying to set ***plan_cache_mode*** to ***force_custom_plan*** because I don't want it to switch to generic plan. I'm using Hikari to manage the datasource. How do I set it in the HikariDataSource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the parameter on the database or user level:

```
CREATE ROLE|DATABASE somename SET plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan;
```

Then all new connections as that user or to that database get that setting.

Comment: I would rather set it in the application instead of in the database, because it's only specific endpoints that I want to apply this to.

Comment: Then run the `SET` whenever you open a database connection.